# Trying to parse model data from JSON in MVC3

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a project where I need to have two separate JSON lists which means I cannot use JsonResult in my controller so I need to parse client-side. I use the following to parse my list to Json and then send the string in my view model from the [Newtonsoft.Json](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/) package:

```
Model.JsonAllActiveItems = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.AllActiveItems,Formatting.None);
```

Then in my script file say:

```
function setActiveList(list) {
    alert(list)//for test
    activeList = JSON.parse(list);  
};
```

I keep getting the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o" after the parse command

The JSON String is as follows if it helps at all:

```
[{"ProductCompositions":[],"ImageName":"Item1","Version":0,"StatusInt":0,"Status":0,"Id":1},{"ProductCompositions":[],"ImageName":"Item2","Version":0,"StatusInt":1,"Status":0,"Id":2},{"ProductCompositions":[],"ImageName":"Item3","Version":0,"StatusInt":1,"Status":0,"Id":4},{"ProductCompositions":[],"ImageName":"Item2","Version":0,"StatusInt":0,"Status":0,"Id":5},{"ProductCompositions":[],"ImageName":"Item4","Version":0,"StatusInt":0,"Status":0,"Id":6},{"ProductCompositions":[],"ImageName":"Item4","Version":0,"StatusInt":0,"Status":0,"Id":7}]
```

Any ideas?
Cheers

**UPDATE:** What's wierd is that in the Chrome javascript debugger, "list" is properly populated with the correct data even before the parse command. However when I try test it out without using JSON.parse() as follows I get an empty string like list is null:

```
 var myString = "";
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++ ) {
    myString += "<li>" + list[i].ImageName + "</li>";
}
document.getElementById("selected-items-comp").innerHtml = myString;
```

Comment: you have to provide more details. show us your code

Comment: Post the JSON you get, since that's what causing the error.

Comment: Sounds like you have a JSON encoding issue - I've had this before a while ago, but I can't for the life of me remember what it was! :(

Comment: @Styxxy I added the JSON string, but I can't find any issues with it considering it was parsed by JsonConvert() I got the dll from here: [James Newton-King](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)

Comment: The JSON is perfectly valid, thus the error lays somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that if you use the Newtonsoft.Json dll with MVC3, you don't need to parse the JSON in JavaScript. This magic happens behind the scenes. The reason I wasn't able to get anything in my test is that I'm a jQuery noob and did

```
document.getElementById("selected-items-comp").innerHtml = myString;
```

instead of

```
$('#selected-items-comp').html(myString);
```

Now it works.